# How to send HTML string from Cloud Functions to BigQuery using Pub/Sub and Dataflow?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

### Overview

**Setup:** I have a Google Cloud Function, which is triggered by message to a Pub/Sub topic. I have set up a Cloud Scheduler job to send a message to this Pub/Sub topic every minute. My cloud function is triggered, and sends a message to another Pub/Sub topic. I have a Dataflow job set up, which streams data from this Pub/Sub topic to BigQuery.

**The problem:** if the message my cloud function publishes contains a simple string, it makes it into BigQuery. If the message is a html code of a scraped website, then the result does not show up in BigQuery, and I don't know where it gets lost.

---

## Detailed Walkthrough

### The trigger

My function, `function-3` is triggered by a message to the topic called `simple`:

[image]

Here is my Cloud Scheduler job:

[image]

It sends a string to `simple` topic every minute (as indicated by the `* * * * *`).

---

### The function

The source of my function has two files: `main.py` and `requirements.txt`.

`main`.py takes https://www.bbc.com/ and gets its html code as string using `resuests` and BeautifulSoup (`bs`). Then, it publishes 2 strings to the topic `scrape`. These two strings are "`publish_this`" and the string version of the BBC website html source. Code for `main.py`:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):

    import re
    import json
    import base64
    import requests
    import bs4 as bs
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    def publish(message):
        project_id = "adventdalen"
        topic_name = "scrape"
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
        future = publisher.publish(
            topic_path, data=message.encode('utf-8')
        )


    url = "https://www.bbc.com/"
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'})
    bspage = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    bspage = str(bspage)

    publish(json.dumps({"html":"publish_this"})) # <- this makes into bigquery
    publish(json.dumps({"html":re.escape(bspage)})) # <- this does not.
```

`requirements.txt` is:

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-pubsub
requests
bs4
```

---

### The Dataflow job

I have a Dataflow job called `ps-to-bq-scrape`:

[image]

The target of this is the BigQuery table `adventdalen:scrape.scrape` (highlighted on above screenshot, see right bit), with `scrape` as `inputTopic` (4 rows above highlight).

### The BigQuery table

In the BigQuery table, I expect to have rows equal to "`publish_this`", and strings of the BBC website html source. Instead, I find this:

[image]

Only the `publish_this` rows appear.  To make sure I am not deceiving myself by looking only the "Preview", I query for every row not equal to `publish_this`:

[image]

and I get no results. The BBC source code got lost somewhere.

---

## Question

Something is wrong with `main.py` above, I believe. **How do I modify `main.py`, so that not only the text "`publish_this`", but the source HTML also makes it to a BigQuery row?**

(It would also be useful to know if something is wrong with the setup, and not with `main.py` - I believe this is unlikely though, and the issue can be solved by fixing `main.py`.)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can be happening is that the URL is not parsing in the correct way to a proper string. I would recommend you to use a library for uri parse and then parse it to a string.

You can use the [yarl](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl) library for complex uri to parse.

You can see this example:

```
>>> from yarl import URL 
>>> url = URL('https://www.python.org/~guido?arg=1#frag') 
>>> url 
URL('https://www.python.org/~guido?arg=1#frag')
```

You also can use the [urllib.parse.unquote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) library, this library handles decoding from percent-encoded data to UTF-8 bytes and then to text.

You can see this example:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote 
>>> url = 'example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0' 
>>> unquote(url)
'example.com?title=правовая+защита'
```

In case that the parse did not work, can you share the logs on the dataflow job to see if there is any problem in the input or the output.